# JSF - Moving data between datatable through client side script

Tags: javascript, jquery, jsf, jsf-2, datatable

I'm a beginner in JSF and I've a requirement to implement a UI control with two data tables where the users can select and move data rows from one data table on the left to another on the right. Now in my application, I'll be getting an array list of objects for the datatable on the left and the users will be moving some or all of those rows from that data table to the datatable on the right.

Now after some searching, I couldn't find any examples on the net where the movement happens through javascript. Almost all movement examples out there on the net talk only about server side functions which will update the arrraylist object for the right hand side datatable through server side function calls from the UI.

So could you tell me how to implement this UI control such that, the movement of data between tables happen through javascript and on final submit of the page to a server side function, I'll be able to access the values of the right hand side datatable as an arraylist on the server side.?

Any articles or code samples that could help for the above requirement would be much appreciated.

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: Try pickList. See [RichFaces](http://showcase.richfaces.org/richfaces/component-sample.jsf?demo=pickList) or [PrimeFaces](http://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/picklist.jsf) examples.